# What kind of data tranfares from TCP server to client using Asynchronous programming C# and why?

Tags: c#

I'm studying programming C# and i just got to build winform Client that can read from a text file and save it to a list, this list will then be displayed in a listbox and to be used to be sent to the server.

everything is working fine but i just have one question. What data is used here? from the server to the client. is it Byte? 
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Avdelningsrapport
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpClient klient = new TcpClient(); 
        int port = 12345; 

        List<Bok> bokListan = new List<Bok>();  alla sorterade böcker
        List<string> itemSaver = new List<string>(); 
        string[] vektor;  

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            klient.NoDelay = true; 
        string item = "";
        List<string[]> vectors = new List<string[]>(); 
        if (File.Exists("texter.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("texter.txt", Encoding.Default, true);
            while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                itemSaver.Add(item);
            }
            foreach (string a in itemSaver)
            {
                vektor = a.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.None); 
                vectors.Add(vektor); 
                Bok newBok = new Bok(); 
                bokListan.Add(newBok);  
                newBok.Titel = vektor[0]; 
                newBok.Skribent = vektor[1]; 
                newBok.Typ = vektor[2];
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public class Bok
    {
        public string Titel { get; set; }
        public string Skribent { get; set; }
        public string Typ { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() 
        {
            return "\"" + Titel + "\" en (" + Typ + ") av " + Skribent + ".";
        }
    }
    private void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(bokListan.ToArray()); 
    }
    private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Skickamrk.Enabled = true; 
        SkickaAlla.Enabled = true;
    }
    private void SkickaAlla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++) 
        {
            StartaSänding(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    private void SkickaMrk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 1) 
        {
            StartaSänding(ListBox1.Text.ToString()); 
            bokListan.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex); 
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);
        }   
    }
    private void Ansluta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!klient.Connected) StartaAnslutning(); 
    }

    public async void StartaAnslutning()
    {
        try
        {
            IPAddress adress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); 
            await klient.ConnectAsync(adress, port); 
            btnAnsluta.Enabled = false; 
        }
        catch (Exception error) { MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text); return; } 
    }

    public async void StartaSänding(string message)
    {
        byte[] utData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message); 
        try
        {
            await klient.GetStream().WriteAsync(utData, 0, utData.Length); 
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message, this.Text);
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The file used here is like this : Den som vandrar om natten###Marianne Fredriksson###Roman

Where 1st part before the ### is the Title of the book, 2nd aurthor, 3rd type of the book.
Thank you ;

Comment: Everything on a network are bytes

Comment: Is it also used here between the client and the server?

Comment: What do *you* think the call to `GetBytes` is returning, if not bytes?

Comment: I get that. its the "why" part that i want to understand.

Comment: because everything is bytes to a computer. How you interpret it - i.e. what meaning you, as a human, give to it is the important thing. There are layers of abstraction you can use to deal with communications - e.g. HTTP requests for instance, which wrap up what is happening in more complicated and meaningful protocols, to make sending, handling etc easier to implement, but underneath what is sent is still just a stream of bytes. P.S. you say it's the "why" you want to know, but actually in main part of your question you asked "what".

Comment: @ADyson Thank you :).